# Issue installing node Argon2 on macbook

Tags: argon2-ffi

Attempting to install node argon2 on MacBook 2019.
I would expect it to succeed

Followed instruction on npm - argon2

```
CXX=g++-6 npm install argon2
```

Error messages:
    make: g++-6: No such file or directory

Comment: Other messages:

Comment: node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/ranisalt/node-argon2/releases/download/v0.25.1/argon2-v0.25.1-node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for argon2@0.25.1 and node@12.11.1 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)

Comment: maybe check this post too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59940800/argon2-is-difficult-to-get-working-with-angular-8-on-macos-actually-not-working/60288483#60288483