# Argon2 is difficult to get working with Angular 8 on MacOS: actually not working at all

Tags: node.js, npm, angular8, fs, argon2-ffi

I am working with:

- MacOS Mojave
- Angular 8
- node v12.12.0
- npm v6.13.4

and trying to make Argon2 to work in my Angular 8 app.

In order to use Argon2 it is required to install gcc and node-gyp globally.
I did install them as indicated on the npm pages of Argon2. GCC v9 was installed. But, I had repeatedly problems executing:

```
CXX=g++-9 npm install
```

I kept getting errors about stdlib++ . I tried using Apple's CLang++ and got a successful build with:

```
CXX=clang++ npm install
```

I imported argon2 in my angular project in order to do password hashing and verification. Hashing seems to be working well (no errors) but as soon as I import argon2.verify() and use it in my code (by making a verify-call) I will get an error when trying to execute npm run start. Just trying to start the httpserver secured (ssl/tls) with corresponding private key and certificate.

**The error I get is some mysterious error:**

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/node-gyp-build/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/[username-deleted]/WebstormProjects/my-app/node_modules/node-gyp-build'
```

I have seen comments and complaints on probably similar problems on internet and people referring to some adjustment in a Webpack config file but at this point I dont have this config file in my project. I tried other versions of node-gyp-build but not resolved. 
Apparently argon2.hash() (its usage) is working without causing problems, but as soon as I introduce argon2.verify() in my code and run my app with npm run start I get the above error.

Any one with similar problem and how this problem was resolved?

Comment: Same here, but on windows

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and fixed it by installing the Xcode Command Line Tools:

1. `xcode-select --install`
2. `npm upgrade`
3. `npm install argon2 --save-dev`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why `argon2` should be installed as dev dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Installing a new version (`0.28.0` and up) fixed it for me